# Are conditional statements in views bad news?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need a quick sanity check. I'm trying to design my views such that they are clean, concise, and as free from any sort of conditional logic as possible. However, I'm having a hard time ridding them of *all* conditional statements. I'm wondering if having some conditional statements in views is unavoidable?

For example:

```
@if (Model.UserCanEdit)
{
    <button type="button" id="Edit">Edit</button>
}
```

There are not many options if you have a view that has several elements that can change or be shown/hidden depending on various conditions.

So what guidelines should I follow regarding where to draw the line on allowing conditional logic in your views? What are some ways to reduce conditional logic in my views that I may not be thinking of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it is all bad using conditionals in Views - after all the main purpose of a view is actually displaying data from your Model. (And some times conditional statements are required to display the data.)

> However - using an abundance of
>   conditionals can make maintenance a
>   nightmare and eventually readability.
>   It's important to remember to not
>   include conditionals to the extent of
>   becoming business logic, but allow
>   them to serve their purpose as
>   "presentation logic".

**Possible Alternatives:**

*Custom HTML Helpers:*

If you aren't crazy about using conditionals - you can look into using Helpers to clean up things a bit. For more information on that check out [Creating Custom HTML Helpers.](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

*Additional Views / Partial Views:*

Also, as many will point out - using conditionals to make a single view function as multiple views should is not the best way to tackle that issue.

Comment: +1 for second paragraph. Depending on what the conditional is, it may simply be presentation logic. One could argue that the view should have as little logic as necessary, and that any parameters that determine the view could have been passed down to a lower level. After all, if you have a choice between two pieces of data to display (even if one choice is display nothing) then your view has data it really doesn't need in all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Many checks in your code may indicate that you are trying to make one view behave as two separate views.

It might be better to have one check at the controller level and then render a different view with an appropriately tailored model. This way, each view remains 'dumb' and you are not passing more information to it than is needed.

To directly answer your question - in theory, sure it is possible to avoid 'all' conditional checks by having a separate view for each such state. However, you can have a view that fits multiple similar purposes and having conditionals while maintaining readable code is not unreasonable.

Comment: I would (and do) consider this, if it were a matter of one of two views.  But the number of combination of possible conditions is often way more than two.  For example, imagine a view with several different link actions, and each action is shown based on a graduated level of permissions, where the more permissions you have, the more you can do on the view.  So again, I can't really see any way to avoid having several conditions littered throughout the view.

Comment: Jerad Rose - You could separate your project into areas like admin, owner, member, etc.. otherwise a solution using helpers was mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

In the best case scenarios, try to avoid them as much as possible. They start pretty simple but later on it can all turn into a lot of spaghetti code. Saying that it's not always possible and pretty much inevitable that you would have to do them.

Normally you split up your views or (have multiple partial views) and then decide the if/else bit at the controller. This ensures that your ViewModels are kept different too.

--

As a rule of thumb, from my experience, I always try to understand the business perspective of the views rather than the technical. Sometimes your two views might look very similar *right now* and might just need a couple of if/else to differentiate each other BUT business-wise they are different and it's obvious that down the line each view would have many new requirements which will render it totally different from the other view. Keeping in view the business perspective, you should create separate views and viewmodels for both.